# Audio Conversion using C#.Net

Tags: audio, c#-4.0, file-conversion

I want to build a simple Audio Converter (between major file formats) using C#.NET, so I need to know the basic steps to do so.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Step 1:  find a good third-party component(s) that do(es) conversion between file formats.

Step 2:  use this component in your app.

If your intent is to write all the raw conversion code yourself, get ready for some pain.  The WAV file format (aka Linear PCM) is easy enough to deal with, as long as the file is just a header plus the sample data.  Often, however, WAV files are a lot more complicated than this and require much more elaborate code to locate the various RIFF chunks and parse the file.

And that's just for a very straightforward file format that (usually) does not do any encoding of any sort.  The MP3 format is vastly more complex, and requires a good knowledge of FFT (Fast Fourier Transform) and the like.

**Update:**  [Alvas.Audio](http://www.alvas.net/alvas.audio.aspx) is one third-party C# component that may do what you need.  [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) is another.

Comment: Many thanks. Other FREE component(s)?

Comment: I've found very little over the years. My software synthesizer app outputs to the WAV format, and I've long wanted to offer the ability to convert this output to other formats (like MP3, mainly). I used to use the LAME MP3 encoder/decoder DLL (it really is named "LAME"), but it had issues.

Comment: Hi again, If I want to write all the raw conversion code by myself, any good resources can help?

Comment: For example, If I want to do (WAV>MP3) conversion and vice versa, how can I handle that?

Comment: @user534028: download the source (C) for the LAME project and port it to C#: http://sourceforge.net/projects/lame/

Comment: And good luck - you'll need it. :)